# One-tap Android option to drop GPS waypoints while driving

Tags: gps

I'm looking for a way to quickly and safely drop GPS waypoints while driving, with my phone attached to the car's dashboard.

I say "safely" because all the GPS logger apps I've tried so far require me to navigate a complex user interface with way too many extraneous functions, and/or call up a form with various input fields for each waypoint, which I can't mess around with while driving. Literally all I need to be able to do is:

1. Reach over and tap a (decently large!) button on the screen to record my current
   longitude/latitude (preferably without having to tap a second time to confirm), and...
2. At the end of the drive, export the list of recorded waypoints to a .csv or similar.

Preferably the data should be stored locally on my phone, because for this project I might occasionally be on remote roads without a reliable data connection. Also note that I'm *not* looking to record my location continuously as I drive (although something like that *could* work if I can use quickly pausing/unpausing the log as a substitute for recording discrete waypoints).

(I managed to build essentially what I've described using AppSheet, but it ultimately didn't work because the recorded coordinates weren't precise — I believe AppSheet only updates your location once per minute, and I need higher resolution than that. Since the functionality I need is so simple, though, I'm happy to take suggestions for services similar to AppSheet that would allow me to build it myself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions — I later found an app that was *precisely* what I needed. Adding it here in case someone else has a similar problem to solve.

[GPS Waypoints](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.bluecover.gpsegnos&hl=en&gl=US) (by Bluecover Technologies, for Android)

I think the free version covers most use cases; the paid version adds stuff like more export format options.

Answer (score 1):

One application you can use is GPSLogger. This app is not in Google play because author become tired to fight with people who approve the app for Google Play (or something like). But you can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger) and install it.

Start the app and press the button (see below)
[image]
This will generate location file. For me they are GPX and KML

Unfortunately you can't start continuous logging and use this option on the same time.

Comment: Note: GPSLogger can be [found at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.mendhak.gpslogger/) – along with many other nice & privacy-friendly F/LOSS apps. Using it from there also takes care you get regular updates without checking with Github releases etc. Alternatives there include e.g. [Trail Sense](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.kylecorry.trail_sense/).

Comment: Thanks, this could work! I still have to tap a second time to stop logging once I've got a fix, but in "Big View" mode I can tap anywhere on the screen, which is good for driving.

Answer (score 1):

This is also easily achievable with [Tasker](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/) (as long as you understand its basics) and you can pretty much preconfigure it however you'd like it to work - e.g. have a huge button, save to CSV and save that to cloud, etc.

An example setup:

- profile that enters car mode (could be integrated with e.g. some BT/Wi-Fi device of the car or just entered manually if you want to)
- action that shows a scene with a big button
- action for the button to get GPS position and save it to CSV

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!